# Can someone explain to me how props is being stored in this component for React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, airtable

I'm pretty sure I'm just 100% missing the point on this as I'm new to React and Javascript but.

When I call another component in my main what is exactly happening with props in these two pieces of code? What is table={table} shouldn't we be calling it props? and then when I pass props to my other component why is it being stored as a const with the point of it being props doesn't it already have those values?

```
import RecordsGetter from './RecordsGetter'
function MainController() {
  const base = useBase();
  console.log("The name of the base is: ", base);
  const tables = base.tables;
  console.log("The name of the tables are: ", tables);

  return (
    <div>
      {tables.map((table) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <br />
            <div>{table.name}</div>
            <div>{table.id}</div>
            <div>{table.description}</div>
            <RecordsGetter table={table}/>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainController;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {useBase} from '@airtable/blocks/ui'

export default function RecordsGetter (props) {
    const {
        table
    } = props;
    const records = useRecords(table);
    console.log('records', records); 

    return (<div></div>)
}
```

Comment: Table is a **single** prop. Props are **all** the attributes that are set on a component.

Answer (score 0):

props enable you to pass variables from one to another component down the component tree.

```
 <RecordsGetter table={table}/>
```

ur passing the recrodsgetter data to another component which then can be read by another component. props can be anything from integers over objects to arrays. Props are read-only. In a functional stateless component, the props are received in the function signature as arguments:
for example:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
     
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        const greeting = 'Welcome to React';
     
        return (
          <div>
            <Greeting greeting={greeting} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
     
    const Greeting = props => <h1>{props.greeting}</h1>;
     
    export default App;
```

this is the same thing as

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const greeting = 'Welcome to React';
 
    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting greeting={greeting} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
class Greeting extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>;
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

the result output would be the same in both cases. we are passing down the parameters of greeting to another component. Which in your case you are passing the table params